# Tensorflow on Flask: multithreading errors

Tags: python, flask, tensorflow

I am currently trying to deploy a small Flask server on a VM to do image analysis using GoogleLeNet and am running it in production using Apache + WSGI, I initialize the network on the main file before creating the Flask app, a simplified version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from flask import request, Flask, Response, jsonify
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import os

current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
inception_path = os.path.join(current_path, "neuralnet")
image_path = os.path.join(current_path, "images")

def create_graph(path_to_inception):
    """Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a saver."""
    # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(path_to_inception, 
                                    'classify_image_graph_def.pb'), 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

# create inception network
create_graph(inception_path)    

def inference(image_path):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        try:
            image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
            softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("pool_3:0") #('softmax:0')
            predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                                   {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
            predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)
        except Exception, e:
            raise e
    return predictions
#create flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/inception', methods=['POST'])
def maincall():
    path_to_jpeg = os.path.join(image_path, "test.jpg")
    fd = open(path_to_jpeg, "wb")
    fd.write(base64.b64decode(json_doc["image"]))
    fd.flush()
    fd.close()
    try:
        image_vector = inference(path_to_jpeg)
    except Exception, e:
        return jsonify({"error": 1, "message": str(e)})

    return jsonify(image_vector)    

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

I runs as expected but once every few queries I get an exception on `maincall()` saying: `The name 'pool_3:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'pool_3', does not exist in the graph.`. So what it seems that for one of the WSGI threads running on Apache the TensorFlow graph was not initialized.

So my question is: Is there a way to initialize the graph in a safe way on this scenario?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Here're few steps you need to change

1. Define a class with methods to do prediction

   ```
   class testclass():

   def __init__(self):
      graph = load_graph(your graph loading function)
      self.sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)


   def predict(self, image):
       prediction = some_predict_function(image)
       return prediction
   ```

2.create a global variable and initialize it to the model initialization class that you have just created

```
    model=None
    loadmodel():
       global model
       model = testclass(all initialization parameters)
```

3. import the file you have written in step 2 to your main app

you are done!